# Visa application - reason has changed

Tags: visas, usa

I applied for a USA business visitor visa some time ago, as I stated in DS-160. And waiting times for the interviews are insanely long these days - the estimate that I've got on the website is almost 2 years from the application date. Now I have a different reason for a visit - medical treatment, and maybe I'll need to request for an expedited interview based on this reason.
What can I do in this case? Use the same visa application and amend it somehow? Cancel it and create a new one?

Comment: What did you end up doing? Would be useful to know for others maybe?